# SPARQL Transitive Query with Unique Predicates

Tags: sparql, rdf, jena, sparqlwrapper, geosparql

I have a number of triples organized like following.

```
:A :hasB :B
:B :hasC :C
:C :hasD :D
:D :hasE :E
............
:X :hasY :Y 
:Y :hasZ :Z
```

***All the predicates are unique.***

I need to write two SPARQL queries.

Query 1 will find all the predicates between `:A` to `:Z` through a **transitive query** (something like this `:A :has* :Z`). Output 1 should look like following.

```
Output 1:
--------
hasB
hasC
hasD
....
hasZ
```

Ouery 2 will find triples between `:A` to `:Z` through a **transitive query**. Output 2 should look like following.

```
Output 2:
--------
:B :hasC :C
:C :hasD :D
:D :hasE :E
............
:X :hasY :Y
```

Please let me know how to write these transitive SPARQL queries.

Comment: That is not possible with your current data. You can't have regex pattern in a property path expression. One workaround would be to introduce a super property `:has` and use this in the query. If your data doesn't have other properties you could also try to use the wildcard pattern `<p>|!<p>` and query for paths.

Comment: I know you ignore this comment again, but: You have **never** accepted any answer to your questions. That is not how StackOverflow works, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Just accept one answer. I will do more soon.

Comment: Regarding your question. Is it an option to add the super property `:has` ?

Answer (score 1):

SPARQL has some obvious limitations as it's not a graph query language. Possible solutions below:

### If there are no other predicates besides `has[A-Z]`:

#### Sample Data

```
@prefix : <http://ex.org/> .
:A :hasB :B .
:B :hasC :C .
:C :hasD :D .
:D :hasE :E .
```

#### Query

```
prefix : <http://ex.org/>
select ?p
where {
values (?start ?end) { (:A :E) }
  ?start (<p>|!<p>)* ?v1 .
  ?v1 ?p ?v2 .
  ?v2 (<p>|!<p>)* ?end .
}
```

#### Output

```
---------
| p     |
=========
| :hasB |
| :hasC |
| :hasD |
| :hasE |
---------
```

### If there are other predicates besides `has[A-Z]`:

#### Sample Data

```
@prefix : <http://ex.org/> .
:A :hasB :B .
:B :hasC :C .
:C :hasD :D .
:C :notHasD :D .
:D :hasE :E .
```

1. Introduce a super property `:has`:

   #### Additional Data:

   ```
   @prefix : <http://ex.org/> .
   @prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
   :hasB rdfs:subPropertyOf :has .
   :hasC rdfs:subPropertyOf :has .
   :hasD rdfs:subPropertyOf :has .
   :hasE rdfs:subPropertyOf :has .
   ```

   #### Query:

   ```
   prefix : <http://ex.org/>
   prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
   select ?p
   where {
   values (?start ?end) { (:A :E) }
     ?start (<p>|!<p>)* ?v1 .
     ?v1 ?p ?v2 . ?p rdfs:subPropertyOf :has .
     ?v2 (<p>|!<p>)* ?end .
   }
   ```

   #### Output

   ```
   ---------
   | p     |
   =========
   | :hasB |
   | :hasC |
   | :hasD |
   | :hasE |
   ---------
   ```
2. Use REGEX on property URI:

   ```
   prefix : <http://ex.org/>
   select ?p
   where {
     values (?start ?end) { (:A :E) }
     ?start (<p>|!<p>)* ?v1 .
     ?v1 ?p ?v2 . 
     FILTER(REGEX(STRAFTER(STR(?p), STR(:)), 'has[A-Z]'))
     ?v2 (<p>|!<p>)* ?end .
   }
   ```

Note, all the proposed solutions will not work on all kind of data, especially once you have multiple paths and/or cycles. In that case, you should use a proper graph database.